# Friends Relation in Firebase or access privilege in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an Android app in which we can access the Location of other person whose contact is saved in our contact list. I am using Firebase as my apps backend. now I want to implement privilege in firebase, for Example I have A friend whose contact number is saved in my phone, but mine contact number is not saved in his phone's contact directory, now I want is I cant able to access his location unless my phone Number is not Saved in his phone's directory or unless some privilege to access his location is not made.....
How can i implement this feature In firebase how my JSON Tree shold be Structured.
Please Help me regarding This issue

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2CGh.jpg)

```
Root
 + friends 
 - users
    - 9xx888xxx
         hasLoggedIn: false
         name:"XXXXXXXXXX"
         phoneNumber:"9xx888xxx"
       + timeStampJoinedaddclose
   + 989xxxx898
   + xxxx000000
```

Here Si my DataBase tree

Comment: Please Also Check the Image Attached